# Luego del audioClip del Intro, el Theme empieza tarde o se traba al hacer loop

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy haciendo un vídeo juego en Unity y quiero que al iniciar el juego comience un intro `AudioSource Intro;` y luego se reproduzca en loop el theme principal del juego.

Funciona pero  problema que estoy teniendo es que al terminar el intro hay silencio de 1 segundo y comienza a reproducir el theme. Este silencio también aparece cuando termina el theme y hace loop para volver a empezar, lo que hace que se sienta raro el sonido, da la sensación de que el juego se traba por un segundo.

```
public class audioTheme : MonoBehaviour{

 public AudioSource Intro;
 private bool startedLoop;

 void Start()
 {
     Intro = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
     Intro.Play();


 }

 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (!Intro.isPlaying && !startedLoop)
     {
         FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("theme");
         startedLoop = true;
     }

 }
}
```

Ademas cuento con un Script "AudioManager" el cual tiene un array de Audios, como por ejemplo efectos de sonido de salto, monedas y el theme principal. Esto me permite utilizar cualquier sonido usando la sentencia `FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("nombreDelSonido");`

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour{
public Sound[] sounds;


 void Awake() {

    foreach (Sound s in sounds)
    {
        s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        s.source.clip = s.clip;
        s.source.volume = s.volume;
        s.source.loop = s.loop;
        s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
    }

 }

 public void Play(string name)
 {
    Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
    s.source.Play();
 }
}
```

También intente pre cargando dos `audioSource` y en vez de usar la clase "audioManager" tenerlos los dos audios en el mismo script pero al agregar dos componentes de `audioSource` al mismo GameObject empieza a no poder reconocer cual es cual y me reproduce los dos al mismo tiempo o me deja de reproducir uno.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class QueueAudioClip: MonoBehaviour
{
 public AudioSource intro;
 public AudioSource theme;
 private bool startedLoop;

 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (!intro.isPlaying && !startedLoop)
     {
         theme.Play();
         startedLoop = true;
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FixedUpdate se usa para la fisica de Unity, se llama 50 veces por segundo de forma constante.
Si queres reproducir audios, te conviene tener un AudioManager con DontDestroyOnLoad y haces esto:

```
public AudioManager instance;
[SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;

private void Awake(){
    instance = this;
}

public void Play(AudioClip clip){
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip)
}
```

y cuando necesites reproducir un sonido, haces esto:

```
AudioManager.instance.Play(myAudioClip);
```

NOTA: Siempre conviene tener 3 o 4 AudioSource e ir pasandoles los sonidos que queres reproducir, 1 estaria 100% dedicado a la musica de fondo en loop.

Investiga que existe forma de saber cuando termina un clip y asi poder engancharlo con otro clip como es tu caso